# How do I get the max N numbers in row in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

MAX will take a range and tell me the largest number.  But what if I wanted to iterate over that range and find the largest two numbers in a row?

For example, if I have the range [0, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 8], MAX is 9, but MAX2 is 15 (6+9).  MAX3 is 20 (5+6+9).

How would I write MAX2, MAX3, or MAXN in Excel?

Answer (score 8):

Eg: sum 3 largest numbers in A1:A5

```
=SUM(LARGE(A1:A5,ROW(1:3)))
```

This is an array formula, so you need to use use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Comment: Would this work if the largest value appeared **twice** in the column ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - yes, it works even if all the numbers are the same: only sums the first `n` of them.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(A4+A5>=A6+A5, A4+A5>=A3+A4),A4+A5,0)

you could use this formula to find the biggest two numbers in a row.
and this would equate to max2

place your example range in column a and place the formula in b4. drag this from b:1-B:N and the number in b will correspond to the sum of the two highest cells that are next to each other

so if you had n=n you could do 
if(and(sum(a2:An)>=sum(a1:A(n-1), sum(a2:An)>=sum(An:A(n+n),sum(a2:an),0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, the answer helped me solve an even more heinous problem:

=AVERAGE(LARGE(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},(P3),(R3),(T3),(V3),(X3),(Z3),(AB3),(AD3)),ROW($1:$4)))

which let me average the largest of nonadjacent columns for a bunch of students.

- you need to push ctrl shift enter to evaluate such an expression
  (it's building a table on the fly)  – that will wrap curly brackets
  {} around it.
- the ()s around a cell reference mean that if it's blank
  (say a student didn't do a quiz) it gets translated as 0 not #fail
- the dollar signs $ are necessary or you can't copy & paste this
  into other rows and get the relative stuff to all work.

Not that you asked but I figured someone might...